# What accurate offline GPS apps are there for the whole island of Cyprus?

Tags: driving, car-rentals, gps-navigation, cyprus, northern-cyprus

I'm going to the island of Cyprus in June and will rent a car at Ercan airport which won't have GPS navigation (the chosen company is literally the only option for me for specific reasons).

While I'll be based in North Cyprus, I will also visit EU Cyprus.

I was told by the rental company I can download apps for GPS navigation - fortunately my mother, who has a tablet, is travelling with me.

Do you know any accurate offline app that works in both countries on the island?

I want it to show all routes that can be taken, whilst excluding those that can't, such as the small roads between the two north-south roads shown below.

[image]

Comment: There are basically two offline options these days - Google Maps and Openstreetmap based apps. Can you clarify what "accurate" means?

Comment: @JonathanReez Showing the roads that can be taken whilst **not** showing roads that can't (like Google Maps does, at least in regards to border crossings - the suggested route from Larnaca to Ercan airport cannot actually be taken by civilians)

Comment: So maybe add an example route that Google Maps displays incorrectly to your post?

Comment: Are you afraid of illegally crossing the Green Line by taking small roads ?

Comment: @Max Not that, as I know where the border crossings are, but I don't wish to take a road closed-off to civilians, and then have to turn around

Comment: @JonathanReez When I try google maps betweeen Larnaca and Ercan airport, it display a route that goes through Akincilar, there is not border crossing there. I think this is what Coke refers to.

Comment: >closed to civilians Do you mean military bases? AFAIK you can drive the roads inside military bases, but you shouldn't stop there or buy anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Went for Google Maps offline, although ended up rarely needing it (as I'm generally good at orientation)

Comment: I hope that you haven't asked and answered your own question just to tell us that you are good at orientation? :)

Comment: @EdmundDantes No, but to tell what I ended up downloading

Answer (score 3):

I use maps.me (https://maps.me/) for all places where I don't have mobile connection or can't afford it :-).
Openstreetmap data is used for the maps. Those are updated often.